# Remove 'T' from Timestamp type column in pyspark, with the data type to Timestamp Type only

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to remove 'T' from Timestamp column ex : **2019-06-21T06:02:55.000+0000** to **2019-06-21 06:02:55.000+0000** with the data type to remain as TimestampType only. I tried the  the methods : regex_replace , translate and also using

```
nc_data = nc_data.withColumn('creation_ts', to_timestamp('creation_ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

But it again gets the "T" in value.

Is there a way so that we can remove 'T' from column value , with the data type remaining as TimestampType ?

Comment: Could you please add the output of nc_data.printSchema() to your question?

Comment: It is giving me the following for this column. "creation_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)"

Comment: Could you apply this Pandas UDF on your Column ? `def udf_ts(ts_str):
    ts = datetime.strptime(re.sub("T", " ", ts_str), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    return ts`

Comment: I am not getting T anywhere.  `df = spark.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])` `df.select(F.to_timestamp(df.t)).show()` as part of documentation [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) in 2.3

Comment: A more Spark way to do substring subsitution: `regexp_replace('Last_Updated', r'T', ' ')`